# Switch statement on a timer in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to automatically increment the index of my switch statement so my site will automatically switch different elements out.

Trying to achieve this using:

```
export default function MainComponent(props) {
  let index = 0;

  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      counter++;
      console.log(index)
      return (
       //ELEMENT 1
      );
    case 1:
      index++;
      console.log(index)
      return (
      //ELEMENT 2
      );
    case 2:
      index++;
      console.log(index)
      return (
        ELEMENT 3
      );
    case 3:
      index++;
      console.log(index)
      return (
        //ELEMENT 4
      );

    default:
      return (
     null
     )
```

I can see that the index increments in the console so I don't understand why my switch state isn't switching to the next element.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Because you set `index` to `0` every time right before you `switch` on it…

Comment: Also, each `case` basically does the same thing; you should probably just have an array and `return elements[index++]`…

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to use hooks for the state. Otherwise, React won't rerender your component.

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
    let [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
    let increment = useCallback(() => {
      setIndex(index => index + 1);
    }, [setIndex])
  
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        increment()
        console.log(index)
        return 1
      case 1:
        increment()
        console.log(index)
        return 2
      case 2:
        increment()
        console.log(index)
        return 3
      case 3:
        increment()
        console.log(index)
        return 4
      default:
        return 'default'
    }
}
```

But renders happen quickly. You will need some timeouts to see different cases on the screen

Comment: implemented this solution  but the elements aren't changing and there's nothing in the console. Is this to do with the aforementioned timeouts or is it something else?

Comment: Weird that you see nothing in the console. You could check this sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-tamas-4mko0?file=/src/App.js
Numbers are printed in the console one by one.